# Flutter/Dart how to check key in multidimensional json exists or not

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I get response json like this from server :

```
{ 
  gender": {
    "label": "Wanita"
  }
}
```

but sometime i get response like this :

```
{ 
  gender": []
}
```

how to handle if key "label" in gender not exist?

Comment: Why do you get a Map in gender on your first output and a in your second a List?

Comment: Its pure response from server @quoci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a map contains a key you can use [containsKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/containsKey.html).
Small example:

```
final map = {
    'gender': {
      'label': 'Wanita',
    },
  };

print(map.containsKey('gender')); // true
print(map['gender']?.containsKey('label')); // true
print(map['gender']?.containsKey('age')); // false
```

But somehow your server responses either a `Map` or a `List`. So for your case you have to check the type of the response with the [is](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators) keyword.

```
final map = {
    'gender': {
      'label': 'Wanita',
    },
  };
print(map['gender'] is Map) // true
print(map['gender'] is List) // false

final map2 = {
    'gender': [],
  };
print(map2['gender'] is Map) // false
print(map2['gender'] is List) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

After parsing the server response into a Dart map by using something like `jsonDecode` provided by the native `dart:convert` package, you should be able to check the type of the value with the particular key. As you stated, the response will be a list instead of a map if there is no label key, therefore this should do the trick.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Map response = jsonDecode(rawResponse);

if(response['gender'] is List) {
    print('no label');
}
```

In case it returns an empty object, you would check if the key exists in the corresponding object like

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Map response = jsonDecode(rawResponse);

if(response['gender'].containsKey('label')) {
    print('has label');
}
```